# openam/opends LDAP connection error

Tags: linux, ldap, openam, rhel6, opends

I am running a opends server (2.2.0) on linux redhat 6  machine, below the current status of the server while propmting the command 'status'

[image: opends server status]

while trying to check the port listening on this machine using the command 'netstat', the ldap dedicated port is not listed there.
Openam configuration always fail with the error(91) cannot connect to LDAP while providing the correct address FQDN:port (openam.example.com:14389).

Actually I am not sure if this a opends issue or and RHEL6 missing configuration or restriction.
Any suggestion or help is very appreciable, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is installed on a machine called EZA and listening on port 14389. Could it not be listening to the correct network interface ?
I.e only listening on the loopback interface ?

Comment: actually it should be listening to this port on the same machine, using netstat i cannot see the port 14389.
using lsof -i I can see it there.

java    16122 openam   60u  IPv6 5068235      0t0  TCP *:14389 (LISTEN)

Comment: Also I proceed to the installation more than once from scratch and I am using WEB GUI this time.
For the user store configuration it is stuck there with an error saying 
'L’utilisateur indiqué n’existe pas' 'nonexistant user'  (just beside the DIRECTORY SERVER textbox where the FQDN is provided) or it is just displaying a conenction error to LDAP service.

Comment: Since you mention OpenAM and Web GUI, you are not installing OpenDS, but OpenAM which used to embed a version of OpenDS (many years ago). I would suggest that you move to the most recent version of OpenAM which now uses OpenDJ and has resolved many issues.